# How to replace a div with a copy of another one?

Tags: jquery, html, replace

```
function switch(){
    $('#get1').clone();
    $('#get2').replaceWith($('#get1'));
};
```

I expected here that one copy of #get1 stays in original place, but what happens: it is disappeared, as not cloned.
So, I want #get2 replace with a COPY of #get1, not with original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `creating clone but not using clone`, instead you are using orininal object. You have to assing the clone object to some object and use that in replaceWith function,

```
function switch(){
    yourClone = $('#get1').clone();
    $('#get2').replaceWith(yourClone );
};
```

Comment: `yourClone` as a global variable? Why not `$('#get2').replaceWith($('#get1').clone());`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use 'switch' for the name of variables because of a reserved word.

anyways, here is my answer

```
function doSwitch(){
    var $get1 = $('#get1').clone();
    $('#get2').replaceWith($get1);
}
```

Set a clone object into a variable to use.